# How can I get the style alpha.bst sorted as plain.bst in Bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

I like alphanumerical citations written as in `alpha.bst` style, with initials of authors and years, but I would like references to appear sorted as in `plain.bst` style. As an example, I prefer the order

> [BN07] M. Baker and S. Norine (2007)... 
>   [Blo07] S. Bloch (2007)...

to

> [Blo07] S. Bloch (2007)...
>   [BN07] M. Baker and S. Norine (2007)...

Then I would like to know how to modify the `*.bst` file in order to get what I want.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that this will get confusing for the reader of your document.  He will see BN07 in the document, might skip to the end and through the list of references and will (especially if there are a lot of references) have a hard time finding what he is looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED: You could try the following: copy `alpha.bst` to your tex directory and rename it e.g. to `alpha_plsort.bst` (you can find the location of the bst files with `kpsewhich <bst-file>`). In this file locate the definition of the function `presort` and rename it to `presort.alpha`. Now open `plain.bst`, copy the `presort` function from there, paste it into `alpha_plsort.bst` and rename it to `presort.plain`. Then change the call `ITERATE(presort)` to `ITERATE(presort.plain)` and insert `ITERATE(presort.alpha)` after the call to the `SORT` function. Your new bst file should look now something like this:

```
FUNCTION {presort.plain}
{ 
    % presort from plain.bst
}

FUNCTION {presort.alpha}
{ 
    % presort from alpha.bst
}

ITERATE {presort.plain}

SORT

ITERATE {presort.alpha}
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I tried copying the presort function from plain.bst and removing the one of alpha.bst looking at the functions .sort but I obtain errors when I compile. Nevertheless, if I don't remove the original presort function (of the alpha.bst), copying just after it the presort function from the plain.bst, changing its name and iterating both functions (first presort-alpha and later presort-plain), all before the instruction SORT, I obtain what I want.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should have tested it before. What also works is iterating presort-alpha after SORT to just get the labels right.

Comment: @iago: I've edited my answer now to reflect your comments. This version should work now.

Comment: + 1 for SORT. Adding it to a weird journal specific .bst file really seems to change the sorting to alphabetical. Nice and easy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you didn't provide quite enough information for us to tell you fully how to modify a given .bst file. However, I would recommend that you run the file `makebst.tex` -- it'll compile under both plain TeX and LaTeX, and it's entirely menu driven: it asks you a series of question, and at the end it creates a new .bst file for you. Happy (Bib)TeXing!