# Transforming the .bib file to get upper cases

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, capitalization

With the following entry in the `.bib` file

```
@ARTICLE{a1,
AUTHOR="M., J. J.",
TITLE="My Sample Title",
JOURNAL="Journal Name",
pages="132--234",
YEAR=2000`
}
```

and with `\bibliographystyle{plain}` in the preamble, my PDF output displays the reference title with lower case, except for the first letter: "My sample title". How could I state that the title should be shown in PDF as I write it in the `.bib` file?

Comment: Afaik you could enclose the first letter into `{}` like `My {S}ample {T}itle`. But I haven't tried it and I really doubt that this is the best way ...

Comment: Of course I could do so. The problem is that the .bib file I have on disposal has around 600 entries.

Comment: If you're a Vim user, you could add the braces with `:g/^TITLE=/ s/\<\([A-Z]\)\([a-z]*\)\>/{\1}\2/g`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when using a .bst that is supposed to render titles with sentence capitalization, everything breaks.

The decision about whether to have titles in sentence caps or Title Caps is a publisher decision. Using braces to "protect" literal caps is only really supposed to be used for proper names and acronyms, since poor BibTex can't be expected to recognize these and leave them capitalized. 

It seems like I spend have my life as an editor fixing .bib files made by people who were overenthusiastic about protecting content. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

of course, this isn't an answer to "how do i modify my .bib file"...

make a "myplain.bst" that is a copy of plain.bst, but replaces

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title }
  if$
}
```

and then change your document to use myplain.bst instead of plain.bst

do not, under any circumstances, change your plain.bst file! ... changing
a fundamental part of the distribution will lead to tears, later.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more specific on 1) where I could find plain.bst file, and 2) where do I specify that my .tex file uses "myplain.bst" file instead of "plain.bst"?

Comment: I suppose that changing \bibliographystyle{plain} to \bibliographystyle{myplain} would suffice for the second part, but I still need access to plain.bst file. Where could I find it, and should I place myplain.bst in the same directory with plain.bst?

Comment: The answer found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31747/how-can-i-get-the-style-alpha-bst-sorted-as-plain-bst-in-bibtex

Answer (score -1):

a simple solution: change all the entries of your database:

```
sed '/title/s/}/}}/' yourfile.bib > tmp.bib
sed '/title/s/{/{{/' tmp.bib > yourfile.bib
rm tmp.bib
```

Updated solution:

```
sed '/TITLE/s/"/{{/' yourfile.bib > tmp.bib
sed '/TITLE/s/"/}}/' tmp.bib > yourfile.bib
rm tmp.bib
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably that's not what the OP wanted (not really LaTeX).

Comment: Will this approach work if the contents of the `title` field are enclosed by double quotes instead of curly braces?

Comment: By the way, the `.bib` file has fields delimited with quotes, not braces.

Comment: Ty egreg. I updated the answer (Mico, now it works for titles enclosed in double quotes.).

Comment: I prefer this solution. However it has several issues: it didn't exclude `booktitle` field  updating; when the right brace is not the same line as `title`, it is not updated; when there are existing `{{` or `}}`, it is not filtered out; when there are multiple `{` or `}`, it will only replace the first occurrence.