# Transforming the .bst file to get lower cases

Tags: bibtex

I have a related question to [Transforming the .bib file to get upper cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53006/transforming-the-bib-file-to-get-upper-cases).

I have a bst I would like to hack in order to get the reverse effect, namely to get rid of capitalized article title, eg

"This is a paper on economics"

instead of

"This is a Paper on Economics"

even if the entry in the bib file is the latter.

I have located this in the bst file

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ 
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      "}, " *
    }
  if$
}
```

I have tried several places to insert `change.case$` (to be honest, I do not really understand the language, so it's all trial and error), but all resulted in the titles missing in the bibliography.

Is that the way to do it, or would I have to search somewhere else to get the desired effect?

Christoph

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: by indenting lines containing (latex or bibtex) code by four spaces, you can get them to be pretty-printed. Separately, please indicate which bibliography style you're using at the moment.

Comment: thanks. It is a bst I once made myself, and I wanted to avoid having to do through makebst all over again (dbj is lost, unfortunately).

Comment: See https://www.dropbox.com/s/24ygngq2ze8c6rt/obes.bst

Answer (score 7):

You can change the function in the `.bst` file (and remember to rename the style) with

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title "t" change.case$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ 
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
      "}, " *
    }
  if$
}
```

However, you have to keep in mind that it will not change the text enclose in {} in the `.bib` file.

The instruction in a `.bst` file are written in reverse polish notation. The instruction `change.case$` takes two arguments: the first is the text (on the current stack) and the second is either `"u"` to change to uppercase, `"t"` to change to lowercase apart the first character and character in {}, and `"l"` to change to lowercases.

Thus the instruction

```
title "t" change.case$
```

means: put `title`  on the stack, then `"t" change.case$` changes the case of the text on the stack and puts the result on the stack.