# Titles are lowercased in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transforming the .bib file to get upper cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53006/transforming-the-bib-file-to-get-upper-cases)

I'm new to LatTeX and so far I'm happy with it. I'm using MiKTeX. In the bibliography section, the titles of `@inproceedings` items are all being lowercased. I am aware that I can use curly brakets to denote capital letters, but I don't like the idea, it ruins the beauty of having just to copy the BibTeX entry of a paper so as to have it referenced.

I've read somewhere that a `.bst` file needs to be edited. However I cannot found out which default `.bst` file MiKTeX is using. Any ideas please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) MiKTeX doesn't use a "default" `bst` file -- you need to tell us what `\bibliographystyle` you're using in your document. A similar question for the `plain` style is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53006/transforming-the-bib-file-to-get-upper-cases

Comment: I'm using \bibliographystyle{abbrv}. Thanks!

Comment: The `plain` solution should also work for `abbrv`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that usually the reference sources are providing erroneous/bad BibTeX entries e.g. journals, publisher websites  etc. So I wouldn't count on them too much.

Comment: Capitalizing titles is a style decision; the standard styles choose not to keep possible capitalizations in the original titles, other styles do differently. It's important that words that *must* keep the capital letter, such as names of people, are input in braces. My personal opinion is that while capitalization may be used in the document title (but I wouldn't), it's just heavy and cumbersome in the bibliography.

Comment: @egreg “Capitalizing titles is a style decision” I'm not sure it should be. Capital letters in/of a German title may not be changed at will, for example.

Comment: @cgnieder I concur; a really multilingual bibliography manager should take care of that. In Italian we rarely capitalize titles, for instance.