# Titles in my bibliography are lower-case

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file)
>   [Transforming the .bib file to get upper cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53006/transforming-the-bib-file-to-get-upper-cases)

When using the LaTeX bibliography feature, all titles are in lower-case except for the first letter. How to avoid this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you want exactly. You should specify which bibliography style you are using.
Beside this, you can set a capital letter normally for example with:

```
title = {This {W}ord is capitalized}
```

Comment: it should be `{Word}` instead of `{W}ord` (compare the spacing)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this, just put your title in `{}` e.g. `title = {{DIN EN ISO 123456}}`.