# why does text change to all lowercase letters?

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

in my .bib file I have a citation

```
    @article{IEEstd1,
  title={a12312... - IEEE Standard for ...
```

why does it appear like this in generated pdf

```
a12312... - ieee Standard for ...
```

Comment: Try to put the acronyms as `{IEEE}` and the capital as `{S}tandard` so they will be respected and not turned into lower case. And try to put a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so it is easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Try to put IEEE into braces: `{IEEE} Standard`…

Comment: This is the default behaviour of `bibtex`.  You can protect uppercase letters from being changed by enclosing them in braces `title = {a12312...- {IEEE} {S}tandard for...}`.  See  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53006/15925 for a work around.