# How can apacite be configured to use title case for booktitle of @inproceedings bib entries?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I have a lot of citations to published conference proceedings in my document but apacite formats the booktitle field in sentence case rather than title case (as is specified in the APA publication manual (6th Edition). Is there a way to correct this behaviour?

For example, it will print:

Jones, J. (2005). SuperSense: An interactive instrument. In A. Anderson (Ed.), *Proceedings of the australasian computer music conference* (pp. 123–127). Fitzroy, Australia: ACMA. doi: 10.1073/234784975234

Rather than:

Jones, J. (2005). SuperSense: An interactive instrument. In A. Anderson (Ed.), *Proceedings of the Australasian Computer Music Conference* (pp. 123–127). Fitzroy, Australia: ACMA. doi: 10.1073/234784975234

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mylib.bib}
@inproceedings{Jones:2005uo,
  Address = {Fitzroy, Australia},
  Editor = {A. Anderson},
  Author = {J. Jones},
  Booktitle = {Proceedings of the Australasian Computer Music Conference},
  Pages = {123--127},
  Publisher = {ACMA},
  Title = {{S}uper{S}ense: An Interactive Instrument},
  Year = {2005},
  Doi = {10.1073/234784975234}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{Jones:2005uo} demonstrated some very interesting musical
interactions that stole the show.
\bibliography{mylib}
\end{document}
```

This question is not a duplicate as it relates specifically to using the apacite bibliography style and compliance with the APA publication manual. There are other questions that deal more generally with capitalisation in BibTeX, however, I think it's reasonable to have separate discussions related to specific bibstyles as they can have complex and different configurations.

Comment: In your `.bib` file, you may use `Booktitle = {{P}roceedings of the {A}ustralasian {C}omputer {M}usic {C}onference},`

Comment: I'd rather find a solution other than change my bib file - there are 241 inproceedings entries in the file, 99 of which are used in the document.

Comment: You may try [Transforming the .bib file to get upper cases](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53006/transforming-the-bib-file-to-get-upper-cases)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to change the way booktitles are formatted in apacite.bst be replacing the `format.btitle.no.dot` function as follows:

```
FUNCTION {format.btitle.no.dot}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$
      % Two arguments: Title twice: (1) don't change case; (2) change case
      "\APACrefbtitle {" swap$ * "} {" * swap$
      * "}" *
    }
  if$
}
```

Of course, this then ruins the formatting for regular books which *should* be in sentence case. The APA rules seem to be inconsistent about this - books are sentence case in italics, but "Proceedings published in book form" are title case in italics.

Comment: A simpler way to achieve the same result is to put the following in the preamble: `\renewcommand{\APACrefbtitle}[2]{\Bem{#1}}`